# R: force the use of a method

Tags: r, class, amazon-s3, methods

I have a method (`stuff`)for the "aov" object. However, I would like to have the same method for the "anova" object, but without the need of copy pasting the two functions. In other words, I would like to force the use of `stuff.aov` on the `anova` object.

I tried to change the object's class and run the method, but it doesn't seem to work.

### Reproducible example:

```
library(broom)

stuff <- function(x) {
  UseMethod("stuff")
}

stuff.aov <- function(x){
  broom::tidy(x)
}
stuff.anova <- function(x){
  class(x) <- "aov"
  stuff(x)
}

x1 <- aov(iris$Sepal.Length ~ iris$Petal.Length)
x2 <- anova(lm(iris$Sepal.Length ~ iris$Petal.Length))
stuff(x1)
stuff(x2)
```

I found that using this works in the reproducible example:

```
library(broom)

stuff <- function(x) {
  UseMethod("stuff")
}

stuff.aov <- function(x){
  broom::tidy(x)
}
stuff.anova <- function(x){
  class(x) <- "aov"
  stuff(x)
}

x1 <- aov(iris$Sepal.Length ~ iris$Petal.Length)
x2 <- anova(lm(iris$Sepal.Length ~ iris$Petal.Length))
stuff(x1)
stuff(x2)
```

But it doesn't pass the CRAN checks and Roxygen's documentation building... Is there a more "simple" or "clean" way to do it? Thanks

Comment: Would defining `stuff.anova <- stuff.aov` work?

Comment: Unfortunately no, I tried it, but when building the package it stops and says `Error in eval(exprs[i], envir) : object 'stuff.aov' not found`